Unable to detect Tab bar items using accessibility label by Voiceover in iOS App using UIKit
I have four UITabbarItems items in my Tab bar
       let tabBaritem1 = UITabBarItem(title: "first", image: image1, tag: rawValue)
       tabBaritem1.isAccessibilityElement = true
       tabBaritem1.accessibilityIdentifier = "first"
       return tabBaritem1

Similarly I am creating all my other tabbar items and after instantiating respective Controller I am assigning tabbaritem  as below
controller1.tabBarItem = tabBaritem1

But it never detects.Similarly I added for my entire Tabbar ,which works but not these.
